# How to read text from memory in Delphi and print it out

Tags: delphi

When I code my standalone executable in Delphi, I can perform the following to read text from memory on a process:

```
var
  First: array [0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar;
  Read: NativeUint;
begin
  Win32Check(ReadProcessMemory(hProc, pointer(Base + AddrF), @First, SizeOf(First), Read));
```

The text from memory will be displayed without any problems. However when I am inside the process as a DLL I use the following code:

```
var
  Value: NativeUint;
begin
  Value := PNativeUint(Base + AddrF)^;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Value)));
```

Which is fine, but it will show me the proper value at this address (4 byte value), however I want to see it as text.

If i use:

```
  ShowMessage(AnsiChar(Value)));
```

It will only display the first letter of the text at that memory address.

Question: How can I display the full text?

Comment: Cast address to PAnsiChar

Comment: AnsiChar is a single 8 bit ANSI character.

Comment: @Marting how? A character array is not the same as AnsiString.

Comment: Why `0..MAX_PATH`? Any good reason? Should it not be `0..MAX_PATH-1`?

Answer (score 3):

As MBo said in comments, you can type cast the address to `PAnsiChar` instead of `PNativeUInt`.  Also, remove the dereferencing `^` operator:

```
var
  Value: PAnsiChar;
begin
  Value := PAnsiChar(Base + AddrF);
  ShowMessage(Value);
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  Value: AnsiString;
begin
  SetString(Value, PAnsiChar(Base + AddrF), MAX_PATH);
  ShowMessage(Trim(Value));
```

Comment: Is it plausible that the fixed length array in the question indicates that the data need not be null terminated?

Comment: The use of `MAX_PATH` implies a buffer containing a path/filename, which is always null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
var
  First: array [0..MAX_PATH] of AnsiChar;
begin
  Move(Pointer(Base + AddrF)^, First, SizeOf(First));
```